# Node.js + ws - websocket is unexpectedly closing

Tags: node.js, websocket, qt5

I have a **Node.js + ws** server and a **Qt client**.  I'm having an issue with the websocket connection closing unexpectedly in certain conditions.  In my client, I iterate through a list of objects and send a series of requests to the server.  The server then accesses a database and then writes the response back to the client.  Here is the (simplified) basic server loop:

```
// ...

var httpServer = http.createServer(//params);
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: httpServer });

// ...

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  ws.on('message', function incoming(msg) {
    handleRequest(JSON.parse(msg), function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(result), function ack(error) {
        if (error) throw error;
      }
    }
  });

});
```

If I limit the number of request from the client, everything works fine.  But if I reach a critical number of requests, data stops coming back from the server and the websocket connection times out.

I'm wondering if I need to flush the websocket on the server before or after each write?  **QtWebSocket** has a **flush()** method, but I don't see this capability in the **ws** docs.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I should also note that no errors are sent to either **ws** or **wss**.  Data just stops flowing.

UPDATE 2: Okay, this seems pretty clearly to be a problem with transmitting oversized packets from my client over the Internet to the node+ws server.  Based on Wireshark traces, once the oversize threshold is reached, the socket craps out, but only when I'm connected remotely to the server.  If the server is on my local subnet, oversized packets are properly transmitted to the server.  Any ideas how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem resolved after I replaced one of my routers.  I am chalking this up to a hardware issue with the old router.  This was consumer-grade hardware, so I'm hoping this shouldn't be an issue in production.  It does make me wonder how many of these kinds of bugs might be hanging out on the Internet...

Comment: I am getting the same issue when building my realtime game. I am surprised that you answer your own question after such a long time. I hope it doesn't take me too long to debug my game. Aside from knowing that wireshark tracing helps, I also want to know what is the maximum size data you were trying to send when the socket craps out? I have posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069345/how-to-know-the-reason-why-a-websocket-client-is-closed-unexpectedly

Comment: I wish I could remember the critical size of the packets, but it's been a long time since I've seen this problem. I have no idea about your network architecture, but I'd make sure your server is connected to the Internet over copper rather than wireless. Also, I switched to AWS in January of this year and then GCP and none of their servers have had the problem. I really do think it was an issue/bug with my old router.