# How to know the reason why a websocket client is closed unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a browser game using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) module. But sometimes a client on a distant computer will close connection for unknown reason when playing the game for a while. The screen just freezes when the connection is closed. I don't have this problem testing it on local server computer.

I have this `ws` listner on my server:

```
const WSServer = WebSocket.Server;
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

let wss = new WSServer({
    server,
});
wss.on('connection', function(ws, req) {
    const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log(ip + ' connected');

  if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
     const id = req.headers['sec-websocket-key'];

     gameServer.socketActions(ip, ws, wss.clients);
  }

  ws.on('error', function(err) {
      logger.debug('Found error: ' + err);
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {
      logger.debug(ip + ' disconnected.');
  });

});
```

So when the client connection is closed unexpectedly it just tells me some ip disconnected.

Comment: @guest271314 that's not a problem.

Comment: _"The screen just freezes when the connection is closed."_ Not entirely sure what issue is? What is error message, if any? Do you mean that when a user closes `WebSocket` connection the browser of any user that is connected to the server freezes?

Comment: @guest271314 There is no error message. The connection just closes, with the browser still opening.

Comment: How is that related to browser freezing? Any user can close the connection at any time, yes? It is not clear what issue is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @guest271314 I didn't say the browser freezes. I said the browser screen freezes. This is a GAME. when the connection is closed the screen freezes.

Comment: What do you mean by "the browser screen freezes"? When a user connected to the `WebSocket` server closes connection? How is that possible? What action does What does `gameServer.socketActions(ip, ws, wss.clients)` perform? Is the issue related to the "GAME"?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't know why that's why I ask the question here.  I am asking the question to see if it is possible to get a reason message from connection close unexpectedly. I am not asking a question about how my game should work.

Comment: _"I am asking the question to see if it is possible to get a reason message from connection close unexpectedly"_ does not appear at original Question. Instead, the inquiry appears to be concerning "browser screen freezes".

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at [plnkr](https://plnkr.co)? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, [How do I test my WebSocket which is developed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097345/how-do-i-test-my-websocket-which-is-developed-in-javascript), [Websocket connection keeps prematurely closing the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564517/websocket-connection-keeps-prematurely-closing-the-connection)

Comment: @guest271314 The question is in the title. I don't understand why you are saying this.

Comment: Your question is not clear from this vantage point. As suggested by Brad, you can use `wireshark`, or even `netcat` to monitor your network. Or, go further, depending on how in depth you want to travel the path of network monitoring. Though if a user decides to disconnect from your server, for whatever reason, you cannot force that user to provide you with their reason.

Comment: This poor OP has been beaten-up quite a lot for a perfectly innocent question!  Of course you cannot prevent disconnects, but if it happens a lot you might want to know why.  You might want to know whether the client closed it on purpose, or the server closed it, or... a back-hoe cut your cable or something ;)

Answer (score 0):

> But sometimes a client on a distant computer will close connection for unknown reason when playing the game for a while.

Welcome to The Internet™, a notoriously hostile environment where anything that can go wrong, will.

Seriously, people cut fiber with backhoes all the time.  Sometimes floods cause power outages.  Other times, someone's laptop battery died.  Lots of people use wireless access of some sort or another which is subject to all sorts of interference... by design!  You won't ever really know why this happens.  Eventually, a bunch of packets get lost, some threshold is exceeded, and the problem works its way through the layers.

A properly built application will deal with this gracefully.  You can try to reconnect if you want.

Comment: Reconnect is not an option because this is a realtime game. And in fact the other computer is not really very far away. It is just sitting at the other room of my home.

Comment: @newguy but your server could be in japan

Comment: @newguy You'd rather abandon the game than reconnect?  Why not pause it until the other party reconnects?  It doesn't have to be far away to have connectivity issues.

Comment: @charlietfl the server is my local computer.

Comment: @newguy Fortunately for you, you can fire up a packet sniffer like Wireshark and see what's happening over the wire.  Really though, you should just fix your application to deal with connectivity issues.  (I bet you use WiFi, yeah?  Did you know you're sharing that physical medium with everybody around you, as well as a ton of WiFi and other devices?  It's an unlicensed band...)

Comment: @Brad I said it is a "realtime" game. Client can connect at any time and join the game or close the browser at any time without affecting the game. It has no "PAUSE" and no stop and runs 24/7/365.

Comment: @newguy Oh good, then it doesn't matter if someone gets disconnected and reconnects.  Look, your desire for perfect connectivity is not reality, and there's nothing you can do about that aside from gracefully work around the problem.

Comment: I don't desire perfect connectivity. I just want to know why the connection is closed at a stable network environment. Now it doesn't tell me any reason. I can't imagine this happens a hundred times a day. Maybe something is wrong at the client side?

Comment: @newguy _"I just want to know why the connection is closed at a stable network environment."_ That is a different inquiry from _"The screen just freezes when the connection is closed."_

Comment: @guest271314 I just tell what I see. I can see that the connection is closed on the server. On the client the browser screen freezes.

Comment: @newguy How is a browser screen freezing related to a `WebSocket` connection closing? Does your gaming application perform an action when a user disconnects from the server?

Comment: @guest271314 Have you played any realtime online browser game before? When your connection is lost you can do nothing on the screen.

Comment: @guest271314 Seems he is describing "freezing" as what his application does, not as in actually locking up the browser.  Although at this point, who knows.

Comment: @newguy The only game have played online is chess. Though chess is not really a "game" as such; no chance is involved in chess. Though, if connectivity were an issue, you could save the positions of the pieces constantly. When reconnected, resume where stored positions indicate. _"When your connection is lost you can do nothing on the screen."_ Well, you cannot force an individual to remain connected to your server indefinitely - nor compel a user to provide a reason for why they decide to not be connected to your server.

Comment: @newguy Big assumption that your network is stable.  Big, big assumption.  Especially because you haven't done what I told you do and go see what's happening over the wire with a packet sniffer.  I told you exactly what to do to diagnose your problem, but you didn't do that.  Also, network problems do happen hundreds of times a day to varying degrees.  Technically speaking, just rotating your phone around causes brief losses of connectivity as antennas aren't polarized in the right directions and what not.  Normally this all recovers, and Websocket is over TCP which helps.

Comment: @Brad I may need to use WireShark but the server and client sends a few hundreds messages per second so I imagine there are a lot of messages to search around after a few minutes especially I don't know what kind of code it is sending when it gives no obvious signal other than closing the connection. I just wonder if someone has similar problem before and can tell me what could be happening. I might need to get a coffee before I start doing this.

Comment: @newguy The WebSocket layer isn't going to know or care about the underlying protocol.  If you fire up Wireshark, you'll find out really quick what layer your problem is on, and then you can further debug.  Look for TCP retransmits and such.  There are nice graphs to look at for this in Wireshark... it's a tool, you don't have to inspect your raw packet data by hand.

Comment: While this answer is generally good advice, it is not actually helpful.  Simply saying "you will never know why" is not an answer.  Suppose you developed a WS app and it disconnected every single connection almost immediately.  You would want to figure-out why this happens and fix it, and you would not just accept that "you will never know why".  Sometimes it's a back-hoe, but sometimes it might be something that you can fix.

Comment: @NickPerkins Ah, but this is a question about Web Sockets, and indeed there is no way to know why at that layer.  That's why this is the answer.  If you want to actually debug network conditions, you can't do that at the application layer.  At best, you can pull out Wireshark or some other packet sniffer and hope there are clues on your end as to what's going on.